# Java Selenium: how to parse through the page source.?

Tags: java, xml, selenium-webdriver

I've the following XML as only output displayed on a page. I read it as a page source and parsing through each node value using document builder. But unfortunately I'm unable to get any values being read. Count of Node list gives me zero(0) only.

Below is my code

```
String response = driver.getPageSource();

DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();      
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response)));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nList;
nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(words[0]);     //words[0]="exceptionList"
System.out.println("nList " + nList.getLength()); -- gives total length as zero
nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("exceptionList");
System.out.println("nList " + nList.getLength()); -- gives total length as zero
```

and XML here for reference.

```
<Resultant>
    <exceptionDetails>
        <exceptionList>
            <code>ABC</code>
            <message>Invalid Value</message>
        </exceptionList>
        <exceptionList>
            <code>ABZ</code>
            <message>Invalid Structure</message>
        </exceptionList>
    </exceptionDetails>
    <Result>
        <code>1234</code>
        <Details>
            <Detail>
                <System type="A">Admin</System>
                <Type>full</Type>
                <Date>2010-02-08</Date>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <System type="B">Beneficiary</System>
                <Type>full</Type>
                <Date>2015-10-05</Date>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <System type="C">Customer</System>
                <Type>Partial</Type>
                <Date>2010-11-01</Date>
            </Detail>
        </Details>
    </swiftBic>
</Resultant>
```

I can able to get the values of type using getAttribute, but unable to get any node values. Please help over here and correct me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;


public class FindElements {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{

        String response =" <Resultant> " +
   " <exceptionDetails> " +
       " <exceptionList> " +
           " <code> ABC</code> " +
           " <message> Invalid Value</message> " +
       " </exceptionList> " +
       " <exceptionList> " +
           " <code> ABZ</code> " +
           " <message> Invalid Structure</message> " +
       " </exceptionList> " +
   " </exceptionDetails> " +
   " <Result> " +
       " <code> 1234</code> " +
       " <Details> " +
           " <Detail> " +
               " <System type=\"A\"> Admin</System> " +
               " <Type> full</Type> " +
               " <Date> 2010-02-08</Date> " +
           " </Detail> " +
           " <Detail> " +
               " <System type=\"B\"> Beneficiary</System> " +
               " <Type> full</Type> " +
               " <Date>2015-10-05</Date> " +
           " </Detail> " +
           " <Detail> " +
               " <System type=\"C\"> Customer</System> " +
               " <Type> Partial</Type> " +
               " <Date>2010-11-01</Date> " +
           " </Detail> " +
       " </Details> " +
   " </Result> " +
"</Resultant> " ;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();      
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response)));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList;
        nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("exceptionList");   
        System.out.println("nList " + nList.getLength());
        nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Details");
        System.out.println("nList " + nList.getLength());


    }
}
```

**It has output as following:**

```
nList 2
nList 1
```

Also there were some errors in your xml:

`</Result>` was missing and 
`</swiftBic>` had no opening tag.

Comment: Thanks Kushal for the reply. The count works when I enter the response as mentioned by you, but I am giving the response as a driver.getpagesource() using selenium command. The XML provided is for reference only, as it directly gets from the view page source. Can you provide your suggestion over here. thanks

Comment: Sorry.. don't know.